# SimpleFTPUpload on Mac Os X

Tags: cocoa, objective-c-2.0

I was reading a post from you about a `[3334:303] File read error` error while trying to upload files via `SimpleFTP` source code. I am experiencing the same problem, I am using `SimpleFTPUpload` on a Mac Os X project. The file exists but when it gets to

```
bytesRead = [self.fileStream read:self.buffer maxLength:kSendBufferSize];

bytesread returns -1 and the apps gives the "[3334:303] File read error" error.
```

Did you happen to find a solution for this ?

many thanks,

Alfonso Tesauro
Mac Os Developer

Answer (score 0):

From what you've said, I take it that SimpleFTP is an OpenSource project.

In the code for that project, look for:

```
File read error
```

and see what's in that region.

Another idea is to add a:

```
NSLog(@"%@", errorReason);
```

Where errorReason is whatever is holding the error number at the time. Without details on the SimpleFTP scripts, one can't ascertain what's going on.

```
File read error
```

Is an ambiguous error and isn't a standard debugger error.